# Why does using a Boolean cause distortions in glass?

Tags: materials, glass, boolean-modifier

The glass material I'm using is just a Principled BSDF with transmission set to 1 (Cycles, Blender 3.6.0). When I add a Boolean to the glass you can see it introduces distortions. Even if I apply the Boolean they're still there. Is there anything that can fix this?

(The glass cylinder is hollow in the center)

[image: Glass with Boolean and distortions]
[image: Glass with no Boolean and no distortions]

Comment: Hello and welcome. The *Boolean Modifier* is not topology friendly and its use will usually require you to manually clean up your mesh. Without getting more details, like seeing the topology, we won't be able to help. You can also share your blend file https://blend-exchange.com